# undeclared identifiers when using nmake to build Z3

Tags: z3

I am trying to build Z3 from the x64 native tools command prompt for Visual Studio 2017.

After using `python scripts/mk_make.py -x`, I proceeded in doing

```
cd build
nmake
```

as the documenation describes.
However, I got the following trace:

```
//eveything above compiles fine
    gparams.cpp
    hash.cpp
    hwf.cpp
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(356): error C2065: '_MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT': undeclared identifier
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(356): error C3861: '_mm_round_pd': identifier not found
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(357): error C2065: '_MM_FROUND_TO_POS_INF': undeclared identifier
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(357): error C3861: '_mm_round_pd': identifier not found
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(358): error C2065: '_MM_FROUND_TO_NEG_INF': undeclared identifier
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(358): error C3861: '_mm_round_pd': identifier not found
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(359): error C2065: '_MM_FROUND_TO_ZERO': undeclared identifier
    ..\src\util\hwf.cpp(359): error C3861: '_mm_round_pd': identifier not found
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, thanks! It was missing a header include (smmintrin.h).